# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Practices.Unity.resources

Tags: c#, unity-container, enterprise-library

I am getting that error and not get root cause as of now , please help me

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.resources,
>   Version=2.0.414.0, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same error! Were you able to resolve this?